# How can I test Flask jsonify in the REPL?

Tags: python, flask

I want to do some experiments with the behavior of Flask's `jsonify` in the REPL. But it seems I can't invoke it outside of an app context. Is there an easy way to set up an acceptable environment?

```
~ $ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Dec  7 2015, 21:16:24) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from flask import jsonify
>>> jsonify([1,2,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 234, in jsonify
    if current_app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] \
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 302, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 34, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of application context')
RuntimeError: working outside of application context
```